# Does string contain Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am writing a tutorial page for JavaScript and to prevent xss I want to check if the user's input contains any ajax and if it does return an error string.  Also any other elements that could be used for xss in the input should make it error.  What would the code for this be?

Comment: So you are writing a tutorial but you clearly doesn't know enough about the subject to do it properly. Trying to check the users input for dangerous code is really complex and if someone really want to get around it they probably will. Just disallowing ajax is a very thin start, then your malicious user encodes it and appends a new script tag with the decoded content (or just uses eval()). If you allow users to post script-tags at all then you are as good as compromised already.

Comment: +1 to @Karl-JohanSjögren - maybe there's a JS sandbox framework you can use, and then you can blame exploits on them.

Comment: yes, I was thinking about only allowing script tags to jquery and the js that the user inputted.  Also I could check to see if there are any eval() in the code.  also some parts of [this js](https://github.com/asvd/jailed/blob/master/demos/web/console/plugin.js) could be used in the parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining a `RegExp` including methods, strings which should not pass validation , utilize `RegExp.prototype.test()` with string as argument

```js
var re = /XMLHttpRequest|.\.ajax|.\.get|.\.post|.\.getScript|script/;
var str = "$.post";
var res = re.test(str) ? new Error("error") : str;
console.log(res)
```

Comment: But for example, `$(selector').get()` isn't an ajax method.

Comment: You are not checking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API either.

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, good example. `RegExp` would require testing , refining ; post attempts to convey a possible pattern of how to approach requirement

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren Yes, `RegExp` could be added to ; also `href` of `a` elements , `form` `action` attributes , `css` `background` or `background-image` `url()` . Post attempts to begin pattern ; pattern would require adjustments to address more or every possible method of calling script or ajax from `html` , `css` , `js`